# Migrations in Laravel are not been placed in 'database\migrations' folder

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

I'm making a migration in laravel like this:

```
php artisan make:migration create_tasks_table
```

and then I get a message from the console like this:

```
Created Migration: 2017_04_03_002411_create_tasks_table
```

But when I go to the 'database\migrations' directory there's no .php file related to the migration I made.

Why is this happening?

Comment: Any help would be very appreciated :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It could be that your IDE is not updating the filesystem. What i would suggest is to use the terminal to navigate to the migrations directory and list the content of the directory to see if its truely empty.

Comment: Thank you very much! I'm using codeanywhere IDE so I had to refresh the page to see the files. I feel so dumb. Thanks.

Comment: Can you vote and accept the answer if this has been helpful

Comment: I'm sorry. My reputation is very low. I need at least 15 points to vote. That's why i didn't do it.